# Members Search for Wordpress Buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I need help please.
when I search for a user it doesn’t return any results, please could you please tell me what to do?? WP 4.5.1 BuddyPress 2.5.2

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url();?>">
<label>
    <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( "Search for:", 'buddyapp' );?></span>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( "Search...",'buddyapp' );?>" value="" name="s">
</label>
<button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regular WP search form you are trying to use will not work with members, they are different than posts and pages which can be searched with form you have. If you want member search to be built in your theme's regular search form, you will have to use some plugin, I would recommend this one https://sr.wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-global-search/ . In plugin settings, under BuddyBoss > Global Search activate Members component.